# How to simplify the return of a View or a PartialView depending on the request in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently lots of my actions have this type of code

```
    public ActionResult MyAction() {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            return PartialView();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I would like to simplify them to something like:

```
    public ActionResult MyAction() {
        return ViewOrPartialView();
    }
```

Comment: You could create a subclass of Controller and create a new method that does this and then Inherit all your controllers from the new class. Or you could add an extension method on Controller that does similar

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: yes, but how?

Comment: I'm looking at a generic function to use in all my actions. Doing the subclass adds even more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to sub-class `Controller` and add your special method there:

```
public class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected ActionResult ViewOrPartialView()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
           return PartialView();
        return View();
    } 
}
```

You would then modify your existing controllers to inherit from the new base class instead, allowing you to call the new method:

```
public class YourController : MyControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return ViewOrPartialView() 
    } 
}
```

Since (based on your comments) you don't like the sub-class route, the alternative would be an extension method defined on `Controller`. Note though that this gets a bit tricky since the methods we need (`View` and `PartialView`) are `protected` (technically `protected internal`). With a little help from the MVC [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/ba26cfbfbf958d548e4c0a96e853250f13450dc6/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L424) [code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/ba26cfbfbf958d548e4c0a96e853250f13450dc6/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L795) we can reimplement the functionality ourselves:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static ActionResult ViewOrPartialView(
        this Controller controller,
        object model = null,
        string viewName = null)
    {

       if (controller == null) 
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(controller));

       var vd = controller.ViewData;
       var td = controller.TempData;
       var vec = controller.ViewEngineCollection;

       if (model != null)
       {
           vd.Model = model;
       } 

       if (controller.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       {
            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                 ViewName = viewName, 
                 ViewData = vd,
                 TempData = td,
                 ViewEngineCollection = vec
            };
       } 

       return new ViewResult
       {
             ViewName = viewName, 
             ViewData = vd,
             TempData = td,
             ViewEngineCollection = vec
        };

    } 
}
```

We can then invoke them as extension methods. Note the `this` which becomes required:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return this.ViewOrPartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult MyActionWithModel()
    {
        var model = GetSomeModel();
        return this.ViewOrPartialView(model);
    }

    public ActionResult MyActionWithViewName()
    {
        return this.ViewOrPartialView(viewName: "CustomView");
    }

    public ActionResult MyActionWithModelAndViewName()
    {
        var model = GetSomeModel();
        return this.ViewOrPartialView(model, "CustomView");
    } 
}
```